# $y^tv<0,z^tv<0 \text{ unsolveable} \Leftrightarrow \exists \lambda\geq 0: y=-\lambda z$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I am trying to show:

Let $y,z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $z\neq 0$. Then  $y^tv<0,z^tv<0 \text{ unsolveable} \Leftrightarrow \exists \lambda\geq 0: y=-\lambda z$.

'$\Leftarrow$' is trivial.

'$\Rightarrow$' to show this, I assumed there was no $\lambda\geq 0$ s.t. $y=-\lambda z$. I then tried to solve the resulting cases:

1st case: $\exists \lambda <0: y=-\lambda z\Rightarrow$ $|\lambda| z^tv<0 \wedge z^tv<0$ is solveable - Contradiction

2nd case: $z,y$ are linearely independent. From here on out my proof becomes complicated, with several cases and it seems kind of ugly to me.

Is there a nicer way, or is this the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $2 \times n$ matrix $\left[ \begin{matrix} z^t \\ y^t \end{matrix}\right]$ has rank between zero and two. Because $z \neq 0$, it has rank at least one. If the rank is two, then its image is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But the fact that we're told $\left[ \begin{matrix} z^t \\ y^t \end{matrix}\right]v$ cannot have both entries negative means that the image does not intersect the third quadrant, so it can't be all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So the matrix is rank one.

If a $2 \times n$ is rank one, then it has a linear dependence between the two rows, which we can write as $\lambda z = y$. Now we want to show that $\lambda$ has to be non-positive. If it were positive, then take any nonzero entry $z_i$ of $z$. Then $y_i$ and $z_i$ have the same sign, so either the elementary vector $v_i$ or $-v_i$ would have $\left[ \begin{matrix} z^t \\ y^t \end{matrix}\right]v_i$ having both negative entries, contrary to assumption.